# How does a GFCI breaker protect me if my device has no connection to ground?

Tags: safety, rcd

I use a hairdryer with a 2-prong US plug (no ground).  Suppose I plug it into a GFCI-protected outlet and drop it into a sink full of water.  Will the GFCI still trip even though my hairdryer doesn't have a 3-prong (with ground) plug?

Comment: "GF" in GFCI stands for "ground fault" - where, by not having a ground connection at all, could be considered a fault.

Comment: Curious about the downvote.  I looked at the on/off-topic lists in the tour and this question seemed appropriate; please tell me if it is not.

Comment: I think some may think this question is more suited for DIY, since it's about home mains wiring and appliances. But I find it to be on-topic since it's about how a particular circuit breaker works, despite the apparent DIY context. +1

Comment: Should I edit the title to not include "outlet" and "appliance"?  (I didn't know the DIY site existed, and if the answer was "it's not safe" I'd buy a new hairdryer, not rewire the outlet.)

Comment: I'd consider a title of "How does a GFCI breaker protect me if my device has no connection to ground?" or something like that. :)

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom  Currently, the question has one downvote and one close vote.  The reason for close vote is "Off Topic → Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design."  I agree with the close vote.

Comment: The downvote may have been optional in this case.  The question is reasonably well formulated.  But I wouldn't say that it's well-researched, considering especially that the O.P. is from MIT ;) .  There are a lot of pages on the web, including [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GFCI), which explain principles of operation of GFCI.

Comment: If you need GFCI protection to kick in, its because your device went and found its own connection to ground!!!

Comment: GFCI is the American name for what other people call an RCD.  Read more about them here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual-current_device

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name "Ground Fault Circuit Interrupter" is a bit misleading.

There are three wires called Line, Neutral and Safety Ground.  The Safety Ground pin on a GFCI outlet is not connected to the GFCI protection circuit in the outlet.

A GFCI measures the difference in current flowing in the line and the current flowing in the neutral wires, and if that difference exceeds 5 mA (if I recall correctly) it will trip, and remove power from the outlet.

The GFCI doesn't care why there is a difference in current between Line and Neutral.  The excess or missing current could be due to a connection to another circuit, not necessarily to ground.

Comment: In the UK these are called "RCD" - Residual Current Device.

Answer (score 3):

Yes a GFCI will protect 2 pronged plugs.

A GFCI works by measuring input and output amperage. If there is a big enough difference it triggers the reset.

Comment: So you're saying it trips if current goes to any ground (e.g., through a sink's plumbing), not just the ground on the plug?

Comment: No it does not matter were the current goes. It only detects the difference of input and output amperages and sees if there is a significant difference. The difference is mainly caused by a short.